# Whatsapp For Nokia X

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, nokia-x

I wanted to know that how can I acquire Whatsapp for my Nokia X. My family and friends are both on Whatsapp and it causes a communication gap between me and them if I don't have it. I want to keep this mobile phone for a  I open to all suggestions on how to acquire it

Comment: Not sure who voted to close, but it's a legitimate concern, since Nokia's Android phones do not have access to the Google Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

Since your Nokia X doesn't have access to the Google Play Store, you will need to download and install Whatsapp manually.

1. Enable side-loading of apps on your Nokia X by navigating to Settings -> Security and enable the `Unknown Sources` option.
2. Download the Watsapp APK directly from [their site](http://www.whatsapp.com/android/) to your computer.
3. Transfer the apk file you downloaded onto your Nokia X by connecting it via USB cable and using a file manager, send it via Bluetooth, or copy it to an microSD card and insert it into the phone.
4. Run the pre-installed ASTRO file manager and locate the file using the search option.
5. Tap the file to run it, which will start the installation process.
6. Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the installation.
7. **Important step:** Modify your phone’s date to (or just prior) 2nd of August of 2014 (don’t worry you will change it back to the preset date afterwards.)
8. Launch Whatsapp like any other installed app on your Nokia X phone, and complete the initial set-up.
9. At this point you will most likely get a message saying that this application is "not supported" on your phone.
10. Exit WhatsApp when it says that your device is not supported back to the homescreen.
11. Uninstall the official Whatsapp application by long-tapping on the WhatsApp icon and tapping on the red cross.
12. Now download WhatsApp Plus from [here](http://downloads.ziddu.com/downloadfile/23961523/WhatsAppPLUSv6.12D-211301.apk.html) and install it using the same method as the official app (steps 3 through 6 of this guide.)
13. Open Whatsapp Plus app and go through configuration steps. Make sure to use the same phone number as you used in the original WhatsApp, otherwise it will not work.
14. You can now revert the system's date back to the present date and still enjoy WhatsApp.

You can now use Whatsapp plus to connect to your Whatsapp contacts.

Sources: [1](http://www.techmesto.com/install-whatsapp-on-nokia-x-xl-android/), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqZ55KmxPjs&google_comment_id=z13yxzazbt21ehqai04cd1hrdl2gspoj3dw).

Answer (score 0):

Now, it is available for download from the default Store app in Nokia X. The Nokia  Store was replaced by Opera Store earlier, however, the store contains limited apps. A third party app store like 1Mobile Market can help finding more apps.